# How to get the full content of a card using the trello api?

Tags: trello

I need to get the complete list of a card or a list?

How to retrieve it using the trello api?

Comment: Can you please post any code you have tried so far? Or at least what language are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

with this you get the all the lists from a board (boardID), with all the cards in each list

```
https://api.trello.com/1/boards/boardId/lists?cards=all&key=[key]&token=[tokken]
```